# find view post hyperlink in PHP wordpress admin file

Tags: posts, dashboard

a very simple question regarding the Wordpress backend. I would like to hardcode the link of "view post" in the post section.

[image]

does anyone of you know which part I find it?

Thanks

Comment: What precisely do you mean by hardcode? Where would it lead if not to the post's permalink, which is used in _maaany_ places around admin?

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to *implement your version* of the

```
$messages['post'] array
```

which's originally found in `edit-form-advanced.php`.

Comment: thanks found it. Can I just replace `esc_url('http://www.whatever.com');` and remove the `$post_ID`